# Meaning of "getting all its ducks"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> As the Nexus 5 launch nears, we’re getting one more confirmation that Google is **getting all its ducks** in order before pushing the big chocolate KitKat covered GO button and releases the new smartphone to the public
>   Read more at http://www.gottabemobile.com/2013/10/30/google-play-store-changes-prepare-nexus-5-launch/#TT4suQTKYz828wl6.99

What's the meaning of that expression?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57862/meaning-of-duck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not “getting all its ducks”, it's **getting all its ducks in order**, that is, putting them in order.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/duck) has a similar expression under *duck*:

> **get (or have) one's ducks in a row**
>   *North American informal*
>   get (or have) one’s facts straight; get (or have) everything organized:
>       *I want to have my ducks in a row before I go in there and confront them*

Comment: is it just a complicated manner of say "everything in order", isn't it?

Comment: Idiomatic and metaphorical, not complicated.

Answer (score 2):

When baby ducks walk behind their mother, we tend to think of them as walking in single file. To *get one's ducks in a row* is to prepare for an important task by organizing and taking care of affairs related to that task.

There's a connotation that you haven't been keeping these affairs in order as you went along. It's even possible that perhaps you *should* have been keeping them in order, but you didn't, and so now you have to go back and correct that.

In this article's case, Google is preparing to release a smartphone. The "ducks" are probably things like regulatory paperwork, late-stage testing, final marketing documents, and so on.